# In draft.js editor I customized the code to set the Text Style to BOLD after typing "* "

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, string, draftjs

```
        if(text.length > 1)
          subString = text.substring(text.length-2, text.length);
        if(subString == "* ")
        {
          toggleInlineStyle("BOLD");
          text = `${text.slice(0, text.length-2)}`;
          console.log(text);

          const contentState  = editorState.getCurrentContent();
          const selectionState  = editorState.getSelection();
          const lastTwoChars = contentState.getBlockForKey(selectionState.getAnchorKey())
                            .getText()
                            .slice(-1);

          const newContentState = Modifier.replaceText(
            contentState,
            selectionState.merge({ 
              anchorOffset: selectionState.getFocusOffset() - 1,
              focusOffset: selectionState.getFocusOffset(), }),
            '',
          );
          
          // Create a new EditorState with the new ContentState and selection
          const newEditorState = EditorState.push(
            editorState,
            newContentState,
            'remove-range'
          )
          let updatedEditorState = EditorState.forceSelection(
              newEditorState, 
              newContentState.getSelectionAfter()
            );

          // Set the new EditorState as the current state of the editor
          updatedEditorState = RichUtils.toggleInlineStyle(editorState, "BOLD");
         const newState2 = RichUtils.toggleBlockType(updatedEditorState, "header-one");
          setEditorState(newState2);

        }
```

This is what I currently did on the project to set the text style through typing "* " at the first line.
Style is perfectly working but having some issues that "* " is not disappeared.

> It worked that remove last two letters ("* ") But BOLD style doesn't work on the Editor.

```
          const lastTwoChars = contentState.getBlockForKey(selectionState.getAnchorKey())
                            .getText()
                            .slice(-1);

          const newContentState = Modifier.replaceText(
            contentState,
            selectionState.merge({ 
              anchorOffset: selectionState.getFocusOffset() - 1,
              focusOffset: selectionState.getFocusOffset(), }),
            '',
          );
          
          // Create a new EditorState with the new ContentState and selection
          const newEditorState = EditorState.push(
            editorState,
            newContentState,
            'remove-range'
          )
          let updatedEditorState = EditorState.forceSelection(
              newEditorState, 
              newContentState.getSelectionAfter()
            );
```